# What is the Bug in the below code?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have written

```
        sub main ()
        'some code goes here
        end sub
```

This is the Module that I defined in the sheet1.And Yes I have only one workbook opened and  in the userform1 I have given a command button Ok and when ok is pressed , The main function in sheet1 should be called

```
 sub CommandButton1_Click()
    call sheet1.main
 end sub
```

I have tried these The problem Iam facing is , The code works sometimes and sometimes throws an error saying that an undefined object or not set with Occured.Why the code is working for sometimes and not for sometimes? Do i need to make any changes to make it work everytime ? Thank you in advance

Comment: perhaps theres a bug in "'some code goes here"  ...

Comment: sorry but I believe theres no Bug in main sub becuase When the error displays it pointes to the call sheet1.main line

Comment: But ofcourse Im a beginner I dont know what the indication really mean. It just points to the call sheet1.main line when error comes up.Does it mean there is a error in main function or Does it mean it is a not the right way to call ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one thing I've found that makes my VBA programming easier is to *always* fully specify the object you're trying to manipulate (well, except maybe the top-level `Application`).

That means you should use something like `Workbooks(0).Worksheets("Sheet1").main` instead of relying on the active workbook.

Comment: Yeah thats absolutely right Now its working . Thank YOu paxdiablo.

Comment: So I guess you had multiple workbooks open at the same time. You could have specified that in your question...